# Safari (iPad) overriding isMobileDevice to false

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to change the property of iPad Safari Browser of isMobileDevice to 'false'
I have added a safari.browser file to App_Browser folder and added following code:

```
<browsers>
<browser id="IPad" parentID="Safari">
    <identification>
        <userAgent match="iPad" />
    </identification>
    <capabilities>
        <capability name="mobileDeviceModel"               value="IPad" />
        <capability name="mobileDeviceManufacturer"        value="Apple" />
        <capability name="isMobileDevice"                  value="false" />
    </capabilities>
</browser>
</browsers>
```

I still cant get it to work.

Answer (score -2):

After some googling, it appears that there is no way to prevent safari from seeing the mobile version of the website. However, you can download other browsers from the App Store, some of which can be set to behave like a desktop browser.

[I read it here](http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-1133846.html)